# JavaScript Functions Within Same File Not Seeing Each Other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

So I have multiple functions defined in `fileA.js`:

```
exports.doThis = async (a, b, c) => {
    return Promise.all(a.map(item => doThat(item, b, c) ) )
}

exports.doThat = async (item, b, c) => {
    console.log(`${b[1]} ${item} are good for ${c[0]`)
}
```

I imported `doThis` and `doThat` into `fileB.js` like so:

```
const { doThis, doThat } = require('fileA')

const totallyDoingIt = async () => {
    let a = ['apples', 'bananas', 'peaches']
    let b = [1, 2, 3]
    let c = ['Tom', 'Ryan', 'Suzy']

    let startThingsOff = await doThis(a, b, c)
}
```

I expect that `doThis` will see `doThat` inside `fileA.js` but when running this I get this Error:

```
ReferenceError: doThat is not defined
```

So how can I `doThis` and `doThat` to see `2 apples are good for Tom`?

Comment: `exports.doThat` is defined, `doThat` is not.

Comment: async function by default return promises ,so returning promise from async function is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doThat` is not a standalone identifier - it's a property of the `module.exports`, so reference that:

```
return Promise.all(a.map(item => exports.doThat(item, b, c) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you sir!  `Tom is now eating his apples!`

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to reference `doThis` and `doThat` with only that identifier you'll have to define the functions as such. One way to do this is to use regular named functions.

```
//  export name               local name
exports.doThis = async function doThis(a, b, c) {
    return Promise.all(a.map(item => doThat(item, b, c) ) )
};

exports.doThat = async function doThat(item, b, c) {
    console.log(`${b[1]} ${item} are good for ${c[0]}`);
};
```

Another option is to first define the function, then export it later.

```
// define
const doThis = async (...) => { ... };
const doThat = async (...) => { ... };

// export
module.exports = { doThis, doThat };
// or
Object.assign(exports, { doThis, doThat });
// or
exports.doThis = doThis;
exports.doThat = doThat;
// etc.
```